# perf_event_open: handling last recorded sample

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

When counting for events based on a specific sampling period, how to handle the last recorded sample when the last counter value of the leader is less than the sampling period.

Update:

I have checked the value of `type` which is a member of `struct perf_event_header`. For the last recorded sample this value is zero and according to `perf_event.h` header file, it does not seem that the value of zero has a corresponding sample record type!

To put my question in other words: How does `perf_event` API deal with the case when the workload finishes execution but the group leader counter value is less than the value of the sampling period? Is the data discarded at this case?

Comment: Do you have a [concise example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code ? Which events are you trying to measure and which event is the group leader ? Can you show us what outputs you get? Which architecture and Linux kernel version do you use ?

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita My question is general and it is not necessarily related  to a specific example. I mainly would like to know what happens to data that is collected by counters after the last recorded sample and which is less than the sampling period value. If you are suggesting that this case might be event dependent, would you explain why do you think so?

Comment: Of course it is not event-dependent. I wanted to know if you were targeting a specific use-case. Since, it is a much more general scenario, the question makes sense now. I could not understand what was being asked in the second paragraph, however the final paragraph makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

> How does perf_event API deal with the case when the workload finishes execution but the group leader counter value is less than the value of the sampling period?

Nothing happens. If the event count is not reached yet, no sample is written.

You should consider that samples are typically statistical information.

If you really need to know you could possibly use some form of `ptrace` and manually read the counter value before the thread terminates.

If you read a `perf_event_header` with a `type == 0`, I would be concerned. I don't think that should ever happen.

Edit:
As per the manpage, I believe you cannot read the remaining value from that particular event because *sampling* and *counting* events are exclusive.

> Events come in two flavors: counting and sampled.  A counting event
>   one that is used for counting the aggregate number of events that.
>   In general, counting event results are gathered with a
>   read(2) call.  A sampling event periodically writes measurements to a buffer
>   that can then be accessed via mmap(2).

Comment: But after workload terminates and group leader counter is disabled, does the counters at this case preserve its last written value or this would be architecture dependent?